# Adding elements based on the repeated elements in list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, element

```
sorted_lst = [
['04-0200', 'str1', '1', 'n1'],
['04-0200', 'str2', '6', 'n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6'],
['11-0200', 'str3', '1', 'u1'],
['19-0000', '', '2', ''], 
['19-0201', 'str4', '2', ''],
['19-0201', 'str10', '3', 'p1,p2,p3'], 
['22-0001', 'str5', '5', 'a1,a2,a3,a4'],
['22-0001', 'str6', '184', 'b1,b2,b3,b4,b5'], 
['22-0001', 'str7', '2', 'c1,c2'], 
['9-02011', 'str8', '3', '', 'x,y,z']
]
```

I have a sorted list that will have a list of lists with repeated index0.
Based on the index0 from each list, i will have to add the index3 and then join the strings in index4.
Index#3 will be always numbers - this should be added if there is any repeated index#0
Index#4 could be anything - this should be merged and there shouldn't be any repeated strings/numbers after merge.

As an example, the result of the above list should be something like:

```
final_lst = [
['04-0200', 'str1', '7', 'n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6'],
['11-0200', 'str3', '1', 'u1'],
['19-0000', '', '2', ''], 
['19-0201', 'str4', '5', 'p1,p2,p3'],
['22-0001', 'str5', '191', 'a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,c1,c2'],
['9-02011', 'str8', '3', '', 'x,y,z']
]
```

======================================================================
Edited:
Sorry, new to the community; adding more details.
Please close the thread; was able to merge them.

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to achieve what I wanted..
post can be closed.

MERGED ITEMS:

```
[('04-0200', 'str1', 7, 'n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6'), 
('11-0200', 'str3', '1', 'u1'),
('19-0000', '', '2', ''),
('19-0201', 'str4', 5, 'p1,p2,p3'), 
('22-0001', 'str5', 191, 'a1,a2,a3,a4b1,b2,b3,b4,b5c1,c2'), 
('9-02011', 'str8', '3', '')]
```